# How do I set a cookie `Priority=High` in express router?

Tags: express, google-chrome, cookies, http-headers, setcookie

Chrome has a Cookie flag `Priority` which prioritises which Cookies will be deleted first (lower priority)..

e.g.

> `Set-Cookie: GAPS=1:ZYBtVMzURzU2umKMxZThJ2lVPxy3Hg:SvHhlG2k1Vy5pnA0;Path=/;Expires=Wed, 04-Nov-2015 20:44:37 GMT;Secure;HttpOnly;Priority=High`

I'd like to set this value from express, but I can't see anyway I'd do that ([docs](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.cookie)).

Can someone point me in the right direction? (Do I need to set the header myself?)

References:

- [What does Priority=High mean in the Set-Cookie header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792038/what-does-priority-high-mean-in-the-set-cookie-header)

Comment: just pass it to options, see the source on how its set https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/0a48e18056865364b2461b2ece7ccb2d1075d3c9/lib/response.js#L857

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone, but unfortunately the `cookie` library doesn't just take arbitrary options... see here -> https://github.com/jshttp/cookie/blob/master/index.js#L101-L182

Comment: np, sorry didn't delve into that lib, just presumed it `join('; ')`'ed it, would be an easy PR

Answer (score 1):

So, I ended up just using the `cookie` library internally used by express...

```js
const cookie = require('cookie')

// ... inside route ...

let setCookie = cookie.serialize('name', value, {
  expires: new Date(9999, 11, 31),
  path: '/',
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
  domain: yourCookieDomain
})
setCookie += '; Priority=High'
res.append('Set-Cookie', setCookie)
```

Gives...

`set-cookie: name=value; Domain=foobar.com; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 00:00:00 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; Priority=High`